# Call SnackBar from within an AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, snackbar

When a user clicks on delete for an employee, an AlertDialog shall pop up to warn the user.

[image]

If the user confirms the deletion, then the AlertDialog disappears and at the bottom of the Scaffold a SnackBar should appear with an Undo function.

**Problem:**

When I implement the SnackBar method **showSnackBar(context, index, employee)** within the AlertDialog class I get the following error:

> he following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
>
> Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.

```
showDeleteDialog(BuildContext context, Employee employee, int index) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title:
                  Text('Are you sure you want to delete: ${employee.name} ?'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                        child: Text('Yes'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          DatabaseProvider.db.deleteEmployee(employee.id).then(
                              (_) => BlocProvider.of<EmployeeBloc>(context)
                                  .add(DeleteEmployee(index)));
                          Navigator.pop(context,employee);
                          showSnackBar(context, index, employee);
                        }),
                    FlatButton(
                        child: Text('No!'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ));
  }
```

Instead, I thought I could return an employee from the showDeleteDialog when I confirm the deletion. When the result is not null, then I should show the SnackBar. I tried to implement this with Future/Async but with no success.

```
onPressed: () async {
                        Employee deletedEmployee = await showDeleteDialog(context, employee, index);
                        await showSnackBar(context, index, deletedEmployee);
                    },
```

**Edit:** I would like to avoid using **GlobalKey** if possible, since I read it is not good for the App's performance.

Comment: It looks like you are not passing BuiltContext from scaffold when you're calling your snackbar

Comment: @LonelyWolf exactly. I do not know how to though.

Comment: try wrapping your widget that u r calling Snackbar with `Builder()` Widget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution and it is super easy...

I only had to re-name one of the **context** to a **dialogContext**

```
showDeleteDialog(BuildContext context, Employee employee, int index) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (dialogContext) => AlertDialog(
              title:
                  Text('Are you sure you want to delete: ${employee.name} ?'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                        child: Text('Yes'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          DatabaseProvider.db.deleteEmployee(employee.id).then(
                              (_) => BlocProvider.of<EmployeeBloc>(dialogContext)
                                  .add(DeleteEmployee(index)));
                          Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
                          showSnackBar(context, index, employee);
                        }),
                    FlatButton(
                        child: Text('No!'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error says `Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.`, that means the current `context` that you are passing to `showSnackBar()` method doesn't contain a `Scaffold` in the immediate parent.

We can fix this by using `GlobalKey` and assign it to the `Scaffold`. Declare a `global key` in your stateful widget and pass this as a key in your `Scaffold`, as below:

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

....

return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
```

I call a method `_showSnackBar()` after `navigator.pop()` on `OK` button click inside the `alertDialog`, as below:

```
return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Not in stock'),
        content: const Text('This item is no longer available'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              _showSnackBar();
            }, 
          ),
        ],
      );
```

Then in the `_showSnackBar()` method, use the key to show the snackbar, as below:

```
void _showSnackBar() {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
  SnackBar(
    content: Text('Snackbar is displayed'),
  ));    

  }
```

With this approach, once you tap on `OK` button on `alertDialog`, the dialog will close and you'll see the snackbar. You may need to customize this per your code as you shared above.

Hope this answers your question and resolves your issue.

Comment: Although this seems to be working, I found a simpler solution while avoiding the GlobalKey function. I simply had to rename the context name of the **AlertDialog**.

Comment: While this is correct, I would like to add that there's a [known issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39898) that doesn't hide the snackbar after the duration, so a [workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33761#issuecomment-507954796) is to call `Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () { _scaffoldKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar(); });`